# The color settings for PDF preview are not functioning correctly

Tags: pdf

Today, when openinging LaTeX workshop, I suddenly found that the color settings of PDF window such as: page colors background or foreground, even invert seeting were not working, and I couldn't change them. Before the latest update, I could define the settings or just following the Windows system settings. Now, it seems all these settings are not working. Even when I try to change the invert settings, no matter what value I fill in, it's either white or completely black that you can see nonting. Am I doing something wrong, or another issue? Please help me? Thinks a lot!

Comment: Welcome! What update?

Comment: Fisrt time to post a question. Thinks for your tips.